# Easy question about line up points ?

Tags: geometry

Well, there is a demonstration to prove that 1+1=2 so is there a demonstration to prove if you take two points on the space, they are line up ?

Thank's

Comment: Are you looking for "draw a line in between them"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In classical Euclidean geometry, there is no demonstration--it is an axiom. Euclid's First Postulate is that a straight line segment can be created between any two points.

However, if you want to say that there is a *line* (not a line segment) that intersects two points, that can be proven simply. Euclid's Second Postulate is that any line segment can be extended to a line, so the proof just combines these two axioms.